# Apache website won't update changes unless I exit Vim

Tags: html, apache, ubuntu, vim, apache2

So, I'm editing an HTML file of an Apache2 website by using Vim on an Ubuntu server. I'd really like to write to the file without quitting, simply using `:w`. But it seems that my changes are not visible from the website unless I do a write and then a quit (using `:wq`). I'd really like to just do a write and keep the document open, and then be able to view my changes on a browser by refreshing the page (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> on my machine using Chrome). Is there a way I can have my cake and eat it, too? I know that for some technologies, changes apply immediately with a simple `:w` in Vim. For example, Bash scripts are that way.

The main reason I want to keep the document open is so that I can quickly undo changes with Vim's `u` command if I decide that I didn't like the change I made.

Comment: If what you are describing is the cause of this problem you have a pretty borked setup. `:w` is enough on a normal system

Comment: Hmm, well, I don't know what to tell you. I just barely set up a clean Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu, and haven't messed with any settings. I also verified that what I want to do works for a Bash script on the machine.

Comment: You can configure [Undo persistence](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-persistence). I.e. you exit `vim`, start it again, open the file and execute `undo`!

Comment: I just tested it, and that solves most of my problem, thanks. However, it would still be nice to not have to do the extra keystrokes of closing the file, opening the file, and finding the line that I was previously editing.